# Hide usernames from Calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar list with recurring events and have it sorted by Current Events view. I added the webpart in my page with just the Title and Start Time fields. I am trying to hide the created by and modified by user name fields when the user clicks on the event and the popup windows shows information about it (dispform.aspx).

I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 fields are added automatically by SharePoint in the default rendering template. Just like with any other List forms (NewForm, EditForm or DispForm) you would need to create a new display form via SharePoint Designer 2010.

Fields you are looking for are Author and Editor as for their internal names.

At that time you have total freedom in choosing what to display and even hide buttons, as you would most like would use a Data View Web part (comparison http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx).

For an exact example have a look at either of the following:

1. Change on the actual Event content
   type:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2009/06/06/define-custom-new-edit-display-forms-for-content-types.aspx
2. Or list based use either http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/246651/Creating-Forms-for-SharePoint-Using-SharePoint-Designer-2010 or http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx
3. or if you prefer InfoPath
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prasad_madhavan/archive/2011/05/04/customizing-sharepoint-list-new-edit-display-forms-individually-in-infopath-2010.aspx

Comment: I had edited the dispform.aspx page with SharePoint Designer and added a new Custom Display, but when I click on the event on the SharePoint page it always goes to the first event. If I click on edit it does go to the correct event.

Comment: That is because you also need to set it as the Default Display form - via SPD just select the form and use the ribbon to set it.

Comment: Basically, I edit the disform.aspx file and hide the original form (`<IsVisible>false</IsVisible>`). Then select Insert and go to Display Item form and select my Calendar list. For other types of lists I select Custom list form, but it doesn't do anything here. I cannot find the Set to default button in the ribbon.